# Upgrading Libreoffice 3.4.3 to 3.4.4

Tags: upgrade, libreoffice

I have LibreOffice 3.4.3 (Build:302) installed on my Ubuntu 11.04 machine as shown below. I have learnt that a new version of [LibreOffice 3.4.4](http://www.libreoffice.org/download/) is released recently. Could some one tell me how can I upgrade it through command-line. I have already tried apt-get update & apt-get upgrade, but no use.  Thanks.

```
$ sudo apt-cache policy libreoffice
libreoffice:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:3.4.3-3ubuntu2~natty1
  Version table:
     1:3.4.3-3ubuntu2~natty1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu/ natty/main i386 Packages
     1:3.3.4-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates/universe i386 Packages
     1:3.3.2-1ubuntu4 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty/universe i386 Packages
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it seems that the package is not yet available in the PPA you have for LibreOffice. The package is indeed available and unless you find a PPA with the newest LibreOffice version, you might want to download the DEB installer from the official LibreOffice website; Every package you install in Ubuntu is a DEB package, whether it is automatically downloaded and installed by the Software Center (apt), or you get it elsewhere.

In that same link you provided, you can choose "Linux xN (deb)" (where N is 86 or 64, use 64 if your install is 64-bit, otherwise use 86) in the first combobox. Download and install! Beware the the first pair of links correspond to LibreOffice 3.4.4 while the last ones to LibreOffice 3.3.4.

Comment: Thanks. If I install the 3.4.4 deb package, will it automatically overwrite the existing 3.4.3.

Comment: In the page you linked it says you can have both side-by-side, so don't worry.